# ASP MVC3 - DomainModel & Razor - displaying info from the database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I currently have my "DomainModel" which handles all the SQL data through EDMX.

When I used an ASPX page I was able to use the following code:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<IEnumerable<DomainModel.aspnet_Membership>>" %>
<% foreach (DomainModel.aspnet_Membership member in Model)
   {
List<DomainModel.aspnet_Roles> roles = member.aspnet_Users.aspnet_Roles.ToList();
}
```

This returned the list of all the members from the SQL DB via domainModel.

That was for my test though, now it is a requirement that I use CSHTML razor pages. (Using "@" code blocks)

I tried to implement similar code, but It always falls over:

```
@model IEnumerable<DomainModel.aspnet_Membership>
@foreach (DomainModel.aspnet_Membership m in Model)
{
<b>@m.aspnet_Users.UserName</b>
}
```

edit: error: NullReferenceException was unhandled. Obj Reference not set to instance of an object

Controller (I forgot to add this code in, now the same error occurs, but in the controller)

`private productName_SATEntities _context;` `[HttpParamAction] [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)] public ActionResult Scenario() { return View(_context.SAT_Scenarios.ToList()); }` _Context links to the content generated by the EDMX

Comment: NullReferenceException was unhandled. Obj Reference not set to instance of an object

Comment: NullReferenceException seems like you are not passing the model into the view.  Can you show us your Controller action code

Comment: Code added into main section.  I didnt actually have the _context stuff in the controller, which I needed for the ASPX page. Now it falls over with the same error in the controller.

Comment: If it helps: http://pastebin.com/Na4FWKki is the ASPX equivalent that works flawlessly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should not it be:

```
@model IEnumerable<DomainModel.aspnet_Membership>
@{foreach (DomainModel.aspnet_Membership m in Model)
{
    <b>@(m.aspnet_Users.UserName)</b>
}}
```

? I added braces (`{` and `}`) around `foreach` statement. Otherwise compiler would think that you need a value of `foreach` on your page, which is a compile-time error.

I also added parenthesis (`(` and `)`) around `m.aspnet_Users.UserName` to make live easier: it should work without them, but with then we implicitly control what compiler will consider server-side code (it will definitely not break at `_`, for instance).

Comment: Nope, nout wrong the razor syntax, don't need to block for loops. Funny beast Razor is sometimes! :)

Comment: I'm always doing that, not to give too much control to razor, you know. It's always better to rely on myself.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, never thought of that! Unfortunately I still get the same error. Model is always returning null in the foreach